# How to reference other views in Anko DSL?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm using Anko in my Android project, but I don't know how can it reference the child views I created in the DSL when the referenced view is not at the same level where I reference it.

The following code works:

```
alert {
    customView {
        val input = textInputLayout {
            editText {
                hint = "Name"
                textColor =resources.getColor(R.color.highlight)
            }
        }


        positiveButton("OK") { "${input.editText.text}" }
    }
}.show()
```

but the following code does not work:

```
alert {
    customView {
        val vertical = verticalLayout {
            textView {
                text = "Edit device name"
                textColor = resources.getColor(R.color.highlight)
                textSize = 24F
            }
            val input = textInputLayout {
                editText {
                    hint = "Name"
                    textColor = resources.getColor(R.color.highlight)
                }
            }
        }

        positiveButton("OK") { "${vertical.input.editText.text}" }  // Cannot resolve "input"
    }
}.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

As I see it there are two ways. The super hacky way would be to declare the positive button within the `textInputLayout` block. This is possible because you can access all outer scopes from within any nested scope and the `positiveButton` method is declared in the `alert` scope:

```
alert {
    customView {
        verticalLayout {
            textInputLayout {
                val editText = editText {
                    hint = "Name"
                }

                positiveButton("OK") { toast("${editText.text}") }
            }
        }
    }
}.show()
```

The less hacky way would be to declare a variable that can be accessed from both scopes. However you would need to make it nullable since you can't initialize it immediately:

```
alert {
    var editText: EditText? = null

    customView {
        verticalLayout {
            textInputLayout {
                editText = editText {
                    hint = "Name"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    positiveButton("OK") { toast("${editText!!.text}") } 
}.show()
```

Comment: the lateinit property could be used to keep it non-null as long as you're sure it's going to get initialized before it gets used.

Comment: I think that's the wrong approach for an alert dialog. You  would leak the dialog after it's closed.

Comment: I think the reference can be recycled once the enclosing scope can be recycled. I'm not sure nullability would have anything to do with it unless I'm wrong?

Comment: Are you talking about properties or local variables? Because variables cannot have the `lateinit` modifier.

Comment: Good news here: Kotlin supports lateinit on local variables since 1.2 :-)

Answer (score 2):

I propose using findViewById()

```
alert {
        customView {
            val vertical = verticalLayout {
                textView {
                    text = "Edit device name"
                    textSize = 24F
                }
                val input = textInputLayout {
                    editText {
                        id = R.id.my_id_resource // put your id here
                        hint = "Name"
                    }
                }
            }
            positiveButton("OK") { "${(vertical.findViewById(R.id.my_id_resource) as? EditText)?.text}" }  
        }
    }.show()
```

Comment: I used this method to work around, but it's a bit overelaborate to define an id in an xml resource then use it in DSL.

Comment: yes, but you can generate ids straight in your code


```@IdRes val DIALOG_ITEM_TEXT = View.generateViewId()```


also, you can use a handy findVIewById shortcut, something like:

```inline fun <reified T : View> View.byId(@IdRes id: Int): T = findViewById(id) as T```

Comment: @AdelNizamutdinov `View.generateViewId()` needs API 17, while my minimum sdk is 16

Comment: @HendraWD it's time for minSdk 19 :)

but seriously, make your own function `generateViewId()` then, that would guarantee unique values

Answer (score 1):

You can always elevate a view, passing the context `vertical` manually:

```
customView {
    val vertical = verticalLayout {
        textView {
            text = "Edit device name"
            textColor = resources.getColor(R.color.highlight)
            textSize = 24F
        }
    }

    val input = /*here:*/ vertical.textInputLayout {
        editText {
            hint = "Name"
            textColor = resources.getColor(R.color.highlight)
        }
    }

    positiveButton("OK") { "${input.editText.text}" }
}
```

Comment: It's almost perfect, but this way the code structure does not keep the same as the view structure, readability impacted.

Comment: I myself usually brake the code into smaller peaces and put them into global variables. Then combine them somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I usually declare a view as a property in a class with `lateinit` modifier; this way it's not nullable and most of views are declared in one place, improving readability:

```
lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar

...
appBarLayout {
    toolbar = toolbar {}.lparams(width = matchParent, height = matchParent)
             }.lparams(width = matchParent)
...
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to use Android IDs for the elements you need to reference later, and the `find<T : View>(Int) : T` function. This allows you to reference them from anywhere, as long as the view still exists, and you have access to the application/activity scope.

See the [Anko Documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko#supporting-existing-code) for details

Example case: Dynamically adding buttons to an existing view

```
verticalLayout {
  id = R.id.button_container
}
//note that the code below here may be executed anywhere after the above in your onCreate function
//verticalLayout is a Anko subclass of LinearLayout, so using the android class is valid.
val buttonContainer = find<LinearLayout>(R.id.button_container)

val containerContext = AnkoContext.Companion.create(ctx, buttonContainer)
val button = ctx.button {
  text = "click me"
  onClick = { toast("created with IDs!") }
}
buttonContainer.addView(button.createView(containerContext, buttonContainer))
```

Comment: How to solve: `Unresolved reference: button_container`?